# Responsive buttons for post navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to make two buttons to be used for post navigation below each post on a blog:

[image]

It works, however - it feels like to much code and classes for so little. I'm using Bootstrap 4, alpha 6. Is there any easier way to make something like this?

HTML:

```html
<div class="container m-5 d-flex flex-md-row align-items-start align-items-stretch hidden-print">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-start col-6">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-navigation d-flex align-items-center bg-gray-800 border-0 rounded-0 hidden-sm-down"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-navigation mr-2 bg-gray-900 text-muted border-0 rounded-0">Previous
   <br>
      <a href="#" class="wordwrap">The title of the previous post</a>
   </button>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end ml-auto col-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-navigation bg-gray-900 text-muted border-0 rounded-0">Next
   <br>
      <a href="#" class="wordwrap">The title of the next post. It might be long. Very very long</a>
   </button>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-navigation d-flex align-items-center bg-gray-800 border-0 rounded-0 hidden-sm-down"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wordwrap {
  white-space: normal;
}

.bg-gray-800 {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.bg-gray-900 {
  background-color: #efefef;

}
```

[CodePen with the code](https://codepen.io/losol/pen/qjVgwx)

Answer (score 1):

Having an `a` element inside a `button` element is not valid. You can’t nest "interactive" elements.

As these are links (navigating to resources) and not buttons (changing state), you should use the `a` element instead of the `button` element.

When using `a`, you could use the [`next` and `prev` link types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/links.html#sequential-link-types).

Using the [`br` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-br-element) in this context is possibly not appropriate. It must only be used [for meaniningful line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327110/1591669). But if you can’t use a colon to separate the label from the title (e.g., for text browser users), using `br` might make sense.

You could use the [`cite` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-cite-element) for the titles of the linked posts.

So the plain HTML could look like this:

```html
<a href="#" rel="prev">Previous: <cite>The title of the previous post</cite></a>
<a href="#" rel="next">Next: <cite>The title of the next post. It might be long. Very very long</cite></a>
```

If you need additional elements for your font-based icons, you [should use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669) the `span` element instead of the `i` element. The meaning of `i` doesn’t cover decorative icons.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have posted updated code based on your review. Getting closer...

Answer (score 0):

Based on review from @unor, I have updated code. The code is cleaner, some more work for me on expanding the background color behind the arrows to expand to the border.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="m-2 post-navigation d-flex">
  <a href="#" rel="prev" title="Navigate to the previous post" class="btn bg-gray-950 m-1 col-6 d-flex align-items-stretch rounded-0">
    <span class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left d-flex align-items-center mx-2" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
    The title of the previous post
  </a>


  <a href="#" rel="next" title="Navigate to the next post" class="btn bg-gray-950 m-1 col-6 d-flex align-items-stretch flex-row-reverse">
    <span class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right d-flex align-items-center mx-2" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
    The title of the next post. It might be long. Very very long
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-navigation a{
  white-space: normal;
}

.post-navigation span{
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  color: #222222;
}

.bg-gray-950 {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;

}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79219)

Comment: This is just an iteration of the first question based on the review from unor. Should I edit original question instead?

Comment: Nope, please don't edit the original question, it's not allowed when there are already answers. This self-answer is actually the right way for showing the new code. If there only wasn't this sentence _I need the background color to expand to the border_ it's not clear what you mean here and this kind of questions are not answered on CR.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just felt it was near a better code - however could not solve the last _little_ bit. Have edited the answer.

Comment: I converted this to community wiki. If you would like a follow-up review with your improved code (fully working), then please ask a new question.